# WCF and [DATACONTRACT]+[DATAMEMBER]

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract, datamember

I was wondering how to add the DataContract to my service? I mean, I know I have to create a class, put [DATACONTRACT] on top of it and then add [DATAMEMBER] on top of each members, but then how to add the DataContract to the service (I already have a [ServiceContract] and [OperationContract] running on a service)??

I am doing everything programmaticaly at the moment (no .config file).

some piece of code showing how I launch and add my OperationContract: (I'm using .NET 4.0)

Service side:

```
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(StringReverser), new Uri[]{ new Uri("net.tcp://localhost") }))
            {

                   host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStringReverser), new NetTcpBinding(), "TCPReverse");

                   host.Open();
            }
```

Client side:

```
        Callbacks myCallbacks = new Callbacks();

        DuplexChannelFactory<IStringReverser> TCPFactory =
           new DuplexChannelFactory<IStringReverser>(
              myCallbacks,
              new NetTcpBinding());

        TCPFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        IStringReverser TCPProxy = TCPFactory.CreateChannel();

        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "add" data contract anywhere. You just have to use it as parameter or return value of any operation in your service contract or callback contract. Data contract defines data transferred as part of service request or response. If the data contract is not used by any operation of the service it has obviously no relation to the service (in case of metadata it is not included).

The only exception are some advanced scenarios with known types but that will probably not be the case in this question.

Comment: Ok, so if I got it right, I don't need any DataContract nor DataMember if I'm using simple types, I can just pass them as an argument or through a return value and it works fine. However, if I want to use complex types, I would have to add DataContract and DataMember to be able to do the same thing as with simple types??

Thanks for answering so quickly!!

Answer (score 0):

DataContracts are what are passed to the operations of your service. Generally if you have complex types as parameters you will decorate them with a DataContract attribute.

If your only dealing with primitive types as parameters there is nothing to decorate with DataContract.